# PCP list on contact dashboard

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, pcp, dashboard

The list of campaign pages under 'create a personal campaign page for another page' list is a little wonky. IT has three basic columns 
1. Name of page with hyperlink
2. End date or 'ongoing'
3. Create a PCP hyperlink.

The hyperlink in the first column is incorrect - I checked the demo site, it is wrong there as well. I tracked it down as far as the template Contribution>Page>PcpUserDashboard

In that file (line 80 in 4.6.4) it lists

```
{if $row.component eq 'contribute'}
<a href="{crmURL p='civicrm/contribute/transact' q="id=`$row.pageId`&reset=1"}" 

{else}
<a href="{crmURL p='civicrm/event/register' q="id=`$row.pageId`&reset=1"}

{/if}
```

Every link listed is the 'else' option (a event link) even when it's a contribution page. I'm not sure what part of the if statement is going wrong. I tried a few variations in this template to no avail. I also tried poking through the php but was unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using Smarty debugging.

- Turn on debugging at **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging 
  and Error Handling**.
- Load the same URL, but add "&SmartyDebug=1" to the end.
- You may need to enable pop-ups in your browser to see the window that appears.

Hopefully access to the Smarty debugging will make it clear what the value of $row.component is.

Alternatively, you could just add "$row.component" to the template inside the "if" statement.  I'd guess it's not showing either "event" or "contribute", but something else altogether.